# How to understand this line of Bash script?

Tags: bash

I've been trying to figure out a Bash script file that launches some Docker containers by poring over tons of documents and searching online (I'm very new to Bash). However, I simply cannot figure out what the following line does:

```
which systemctl 2>&1 >/dev/null && systemctl stop firewalld && systemctl restart docker
```

I understand the 2>&1 >/dev/null part.

I also understand that "which" is a utility that basically prints the full path to executables to STDOUT by referencing PATH information (please do correct me if I'm wrong), I believe it's not the most recommended utility because it's not as universal across different UNIX-y systems.

However, I don't understand that line as a whole at all.

I tried playing with it by typing stuff like `which node`, `which docker` and it's behavior was as expected but I don't get what's happening in the above line at all.

For reference, the entire code and its output are below:

```
PROVISION_PORT=3000
HLF_WORKSPACE=~/HLF_workspace

usage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 [-p provision_port] [-d HLF_workspace_path]"   # $0: 0th arg -> ./setupProvCont
}

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
   echo "No input parameter, will use default settings"
fi

while getopts "p:d:h" arg       #get options
do
    case $arg in
     h)
        usage
        exit        #exit 0 -> normal exit
        ;;
     p)
        PROVISION_PORT=$OPTARG  #optional arguments
        ;;
     d)
        HLF_WORKSPACE=$OPTARG
        ;;
     ?)
        usage
        exit 1     #exit 1 -> error exit, unknown flag used
        ;;
    esac
done

which systemctl 2>&1 >/dev/null && systemctl stop firewalld && systemctl restart docker
echo "Starting Provision..."
echo "docker run -it -u `id -u $USER` --network=host -e "PROVISION_PORT=$PROVISION_PORT" -e \"BCS_DOCKER_WORKSPACE=$HLF_WORKSPACE\" -e \"VM_HOSTNAME=`hostname`\" -v /var/run:/var/run -v $HLF_WORKSPACE:$HLF_WORKSPACE -d oracle/HLF-provision"
docker run -it -u `id -u $USER` --network=host -e "PROVISION_PORT=$PROVISION_PORT" -e "BCS_DOCKER_WORKSPACE=$HLF_WORKSPACE" -e "VM_HOSTNAME=`hostname`" -v /var/run:/var/run -v $HLF_WORKSPACE:$HLF_WORKSPACE -d oracle/HLF-provision
```

Output:

```
[hlf@hlfdemo hlf_fabric]$ ./setupProvisionContainer.sh 
No input parameter, will use default settings
Starting Provision...
docker run -it -u 1000 --network=host -e PROVISION_PORT=3000 -e "BCS_DOCKER_WORKSPACE=/home/hlf/HLF_workspace" -e "VM_HOSTNAME=hlfdemo.internal" -v /var/run:/var/run -v /home/hlf/HLF_workspace:/home/hlf/HLF_workspace -d hlf/HLF-provision
b7f3073cc218b70525341c1770aaef17fc41c8e76f858807e7fd6e995594c60d
[hlf@hlfdemo hlf_fabric]$
```

Comment: A general idea behind `which systemctl` is to determine if systemd is installed at all, and then, if it is, invoke two next commands. Beside returning path to a given command, `which` exits with non-zero status, when a command can't be found in `$PATH`.

Comment: As stated, the `&&` conditional makes each step predicated on the previous, so if `which` fails it will not stop `firewalld` and restart docker. It will also not skip anything *after* that line, and doesn't check to see that `firewalld` is running, so I'm guessing that it either isn't that important, or the error from `which` will be enough in some log for an admin to fix the problem and try again.

Comment: @PaulHodges and user3159253, thank you so much for the clarification, I finally get it! The whole command is an AND list which will execute only if all three commands that make it up exit without error, i.e. exit 0, and the which systemctl 2>&1 >/dev/null redirects STDERR to STDOUT and then discards it (dev/null), thus checking to ensure systemctl exists. If not, an error will be displayed and nothing else on this line executed, but the following lines will indeed execute. Please correct me if I'm still going wrong somewhere! Thank you once again!

Comment: Yep, though we both need to note that it *throws away the error*, so it won't even be logged, lol.... But yes, in general, you have it.

Comment: @PaulHodges that makes sense, thank you for that clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command

```
which systemctl 2>&1 >/dev/null && systemctl stop firewalld && systemctl restart docker
```

is an AND list of three commands separated by the boolean operator `&&`.

They are executed from left to right and the AND operator (`&&`) checks the exit code of its left command and calls the right command only if that exit code is `0` (which means "Success").

This basically means the commands are executed one by one until one of them fails.

`which` is usually used as in this example to check if a program is available to make sure the commands that follow it can be executed. They are not executed if the program is not available (`which` completes with exit code `1` if it cannot find the program).
The output and the errors of `which` are redirected to `/dev/null` (they are basically discarded) because here we don't need to know where `systemctl` is located but only if it exists (and will be found when invoked directly by the next commands in the list).

You can always check the exit code of the previous command executed by checking the content of the special shell variable `$?`:

```
$ which ls
/bin/ls
$ echo $?
0
$ which some-program-that-does-not-exist
$ echo $?
1
```

**Update**

The redirections apply to each simple command individually and they do not affect the other commands.

There are three simple commands in this command line:

```
which systemctl 2>&1 >/dev/null
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl restart docker
```

Only the first one has its `stdout` and `stderr` redirected, the other two are not affected and they send their output (and errors) to the standard output and error streams (that are by default connected to the terminal).

The redirections are processed from left to right.

First, `2>&1` duplicate the file descriptor `1` (`stdout`) and stores the copy under the file descriptor `2` (`stderr`). In plain English this means that after `2>&1`, `stderr` sends its content to the same stream `stdout` does.

Then, `>/dev/null` changes `stdout` (and only `stdout`) to point to the special file `/dev/null`.
`/dev/null` is a special file that doesn't use space and everything that is written to it is discarded. Redirecting `stdout` and/or `stderr` to it is the standard Unix way to discard the output and/or the errors of a command.

Please note that after `2>&1 >/dev/null`, `stdout` points `/dev/null` and `stderr` points to the previous value of `stdout` which *was not* `/dev/null` but the console (the terminal window); which was also the previous value of `stderr`.
In other words, this incorrectly keeps `stderr` sending its content to the terminal and it redirects only `stdout`.

The correct way to do it is to first redirect `stdout` and *then* duplicate `stdout` into `stderr`:

```
which systemctl >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Or you can use the `&>` redirection operator that redirects both `stdout` and `stderr` to the same file:

```
which systemctl &>/dev/null
```

Comment: Okay I finally get it!! So this is an AND list of three commands as you say, and in the first part we're simply checking if systemctl exists at all, if not we redirect STDERR to STDOUT and then discard it (that's the correct sequence, right?), and then skip the remaining two. If which does not throw an error, we stop the firewall service and restart docker! Thank you so much for the clarification!

Comment: if I may take the libertyu to ask another small doubt, with the case switching we see cases for provisioning port and workspace path being handled, as well as a case handling unknown flag input, but what is that case 'h' that causes a successful exit code 0? What exactly does the following code imply: getopts "p:d:h" arg ?

Comment: The redirection of `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null` is part of the first command. It happens no matter if `systemctl` exists or not and it does not depend on the exit code of `which`. Also, it applies only to the first command. The standard output and error streams of the second and the third commands are not affected, each command uses its own redirections (none for the second and the third commands here). Read more about Bash commands and redirections in the comfort of your terminal using `man bash` or on https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents

Comment: Regarding `getopt`, you can read its help here https://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt or you can run `man getopt` in your terminal. Either way, on [so] it's better to ask another question about it (include only the relevant code).

Comment: c.f. [This tutorial](https://sookocheff.com/post/bash/parsing-bash-script-arguments-with-shopts/). `getopts` is a tool for parsing command line arguments. If the user submitted the script with `-h` (asking for help) then it calls the `usage` function to print out expected calling conventions, and then exit with a clean return code (because it successfully did what was asked.)

Comment: @PaulHodges thank you so much once again for the help with getopts! Can't believe the help flag didn't strike me, despite having used it so many times elsewhere. Sometimes the ol' bulb takes time time and nudging to light up I guess. Thank you once again and cheers!

Comment: @axiac Thank you for the further clarifications and the links!